# What is the variance of a time series that is the change of another time series?

Tags: time-series, variance, autocorrelation, covariance, time-varying-covariate

If a time series variable $y_{t+1}$ is measuring the change of another time series variable so that $y_{t+1}=x_{t+1}-x_t$, I want to know how to compute the Variance of $y_{t+1}$ as a function of the variance of $x_t$.

Is it the following?

$Var(y_{t+1})=Var(x_{t+1})+Var(x_t) - 2Cov(x_{t+1},x_t)$

(Note the covariance would have a plus sign if it was $y_{t+1}=x_{t+1}+x_t$ instead)

Comment: The general formula of yours always works (after correcting the sign of covariance). It can be simplified in some cases such as when $x_t$ is stationary

Comment: In practice if you take a first difference like this it will be because the time series is non-stationary.